# Is there a way to migrate a project board in GitHub to project (beta)?

Tags: github

I have an existing project that uses *project boards* on GitHub. I want to move all issues (open and closed) to *projects (beta)* on GitHub. Is there a way to do that automatically? Right now, I only know how to add issues manually to *projects (beta)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now do this by enabling the `Project migration` feature in [feature preview](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-github/exploring-early-access-releases-with-feature-preview)

Once you enable it you should see a `Start migration` button when you go to your Classic (not beta) Project Board

[Here are the official docs](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/creating-projects/migrating-from-projects-classic) on how to do it

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is currently no official guide on how to migrate to GitHub Projects (beta). You might want to follow this discussion on the topic: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/6141

However, I created a tutorial on how to migrate from the legacy project boards to the new projects (beta) myself: https://github.com/galargh/projects-migration#how-to-migrate-from-github-projects-to-github-projects-beta

It describes how to migrate cards (including column names) by either running a GitHub Actions workflow or a bash script.

Unfortunately, it does require some manual steps because projects (beta) API is not complete yet - the project itself and the `Status` field options have to be created manually to be precise.

After the migration, I'm also heavily using this action I created https://github.com/protocol/github-api-action-library/tree/master/add-project-items-by-content-query. I use it to periodically populate my projects based on content search queries (e.g. I automated adding all the issues that mention me - https://github.com/galargh/.github/blob/684c316/.github/workflows/add-project-items.yml).

Answer (score 0):

I implemented python script that helps you migrate your project (similar to @galargh's solution) which uses the GraphQL api for the old projects too (might be more future proof) and also allows you to map column names and migrate PRs.

https://github.com/doidor/gh-projects-migration